# How to switch load-balancer from HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-acm

I have a Route 53 domain, which maps to a load-balancer, which maps to a NodeJS Express server ([check it out here](http://my-chat-api.com)). But it is currently using HTTP, so I want to switch over to HTTPS. I also have an ACM SSL certificate ready to go.

I have tried adding a listener to the load-balancer...

[image: image of adding listener to load-balancer]

However, when I entered the address in the browser, it times out.

So, I tried editing the security group corresponding to this load-balancer...

[image: image of editing the security group for load-balancer]

But it still times out.

Thanks for any help.

Extra references:

- [here is the video I have been watching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsVO14-lqp0)
- [here is the AWS docs article I have been reading](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html)

P.S. Could it be a problem with the API itself i.e. do I have to add any extra configuration to the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current listener on  HTTPS isn't working because you aren't pointing it at the same destination as the HTTP listener.

Set your HTTPS listener's Instance Protocol to `HTTP` and its port to the port
your API listens on - `31315`.

> I tried editing the security group corresponding to this load-balancer

This needs to be done as well.  The load balancer's security group must allow 443, and the load balancer must be listening on 443.  The only piece you look like you're missing is pointing the load balancer's listener to the correct destination port on the instance.

> Could it be a problem with the API itself i.e. do I have to add any extra configuration to the API?

I wouldn't think so.  The API probably doesn't care whether the load balancer listens for htts or not - the important thing is that the traffic is sent to the port the API is listening on.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!

Comment: I do have one more question - when I enter the raw domain into the browser (my-chat-api.com), it defaults to http, not https. How can I make it go to https by default?

Comment: Without a protocol specified, the browser is "guessing" http.  https://blog.chromium.org/2021/03/a-safer-default-for-navigation-https.html explains how Chrome recently started moving to https by default with http fallback.  But to cover all browsers, you want to redirect http connections to https.  The easiest way to do this is to use ALB, not ELB, then you can set up an http listener that redirects to https at the ALB layer.  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/ With classic ELB, you have to do it on the instance side, so ALB is better.